# jQuery functions not firing until you resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation Orbit image slider that doesn't show up until you resize the browser window. The space is empty until you even just change the window size by a pixel. Foundation is calculating the hight of the slider on the fly but when the page first loads there's no height set on the container.

I also have a nav bar that doesn't correct itself to its calculated width until I resize the window.

Here's the nav bar code:

```
Ew.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $(".nav").width($(window).width() - 406);
    $(".subnav").width($(window).width() - 396);
    return $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".nav").width($(window).width() - 406);
      return $(".subnav").width($(window).width() - 396);
    });
  }
});
```

And the slider initialization code:

```
Ew.OrbitSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  initOrbit: function() {
    $(document).foundation('orbit', {
      stack_on_small: true;
      navigation_arrows: false;
      variable_height: true;
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

What causes jQuery functions to not fire until the window resizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand fully why this is happening, but it seems it has to do with the size `.nav` and `.subnav`right? I think that the initial sizing of this elements occurs too early. Plz try the following:

```
Ew.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
      $(".nav").width($(window).width() - 406);
      $(".subnav").width($(window).width() - 396);
      return $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".nav").width($(window).width() - 406);
        return $(".subnav").width($(window).width() - 396);
      });
    }

  }
});
```

**This makes your logic run after all rendering stuff has been performed by Ember. Actually didInsertElement just guarantees to be executed when the root element of the given view is there. The child elements or child views do not have to be there!** Have a look at my [blog](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/) for an explanation and a more elegant approach to avoid this unattractive nesting in the code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple trick would be chaining the `.resize()` function twice:

```
return $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".nav").width($(window).width() - 406);
    return $(".subnav").width($(window).width() - 396);
}).resize();    // Resize() onload
```

You can see the difference between without chaining (http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2x42Q/2/) and with chaining (http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2x42Q/1)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the parts that are saying:

```
   return $(window).resize(function() {
```

What if instead of $(window).resize it was $(document).load ?

From jQuery documentation:

```
/*The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been 
completely  loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a 
URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.*/
```

Comment: I need the resize() function though because it's responsive. It doesn't resize on load(). Thanks though.